# Appveyor deployment into 2 different locations based on branch commit yml parse error

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, appveyor

I have a pretty simple scenario where I want to deploy to two different locations depending on the commit happening on dev branch or master. Since its imposible to have two different yml files on these branches since one overwrites the other every time I came about this article here:

https://www.appveyor.com/blog/2014/07/23/appveyor-yml-and-multiple-branches/

The article makes it clear we can use one yml file to set htis up howver I het an error: 
Error parsing appveyor.yml: (Line: 35, Col: 1, Idx: 554) - (Line: 35, Col: 9, Idx: 562): Duplicate key

Here is my yml

```
image: Visual Studio 2017

environment: 
  nodejs_version: "6"

platform: 
  - x64

install: 
  - ps: Install-Product node $env:nodejs_version 
  - yarn install --no-progress

build_script: 
  - yarn ng -- build --prod --aot --no-progress

cache: 
  - node_modules -> yarn.lock 
  - "%LOCALAPPDATA%/Yarn"

branches: 
  only: 
  - master

artifacts: 
  path: '\dist\' 
  name: NINJASPA

before_deploy: 
  ssh root@ipadresshere -t "ls; rm -r -v /var/www/asp/ninjacodingfront/*; ls; exit; bash --login"

deploy: 
  provider: Environment 
  name: NinjaCodingFront

branches: 
  only: 
  - dev

artifacts: 
  path: '\dist\' 
  name: NINJASPADEV

before_deploy: 
  ssh root@ipadresshere -t "ls; rm -r -v /var/www/asp/ninjacodingfrontdev/*; ls; exit; bash --login"

deploy: 
  provider: Environment 
  name: NinjaCodingFrontDev

Line 35 is where branches dev comes come:

branches: --------------- (line 35) 
  only: 
  - dev
```

No idea what to do next, please help. Hope its solvable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally this is how its done:

```
image: Visual Studio 2017

platform:
  - x64

environment:
   nodejs_version: "6"

install:
  - ps: Install-Product node $env:nodejs_version
  - yarn install --no-progress

build_script:
  - yarn ng -- build --prod --aot --no-progress

cache:
  - node_modules -> yarn.lock
  - "%LOCALAPPDATA%/Yarn"


for:


-
  branches:
    only:
      - master

  deploy:
    provider: Environment
    name: NinjaCodingFront

  artifacts:
    path: '\dist\'
    name: NINJASPA

  before_deploy:    
    ssh root@xxxxxxxxx -t "ls; rm -r -v /var/www/asp/ninjacodingfront/*; ls; exit; bash --login"



-
  branches:
    only:
      - dev

  deploy:
    provider: Environment
    name: NinjaCodingFrontDev

  artifacts:
    path: '\dist\'
    name: NINJASPADEV

  before_deploy:    
    ssh root@xxxxxxxxxxx -t "ls; rm -r -v /var/www/asp/ninjacodingfrontdev/*; ls; exit; bash --login"
```

Comment: Yaml itself requires functional indentation http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/2009-07-21/spec.html#id2576668